# Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory

Tags: logic

In Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory '∈' is a fundamental dyadic relation. On the other side, in ZF a dyadic relation is a set of ordered pairs. So I wonder: does in ZF exists the following set {<x,y>| x ∈ y}? That is, is it legitimate to build such a set?

Comment: No it is not. See the answer to [your post in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640180/zermelo-fraenkel-and-relations)

Comment: Thank you, Mauro. So if something is a relation if and only if it is a class of ordered pairs, since there is not the set of all the ordered pairs, <x,y>, such that the first element belongs (∈) to the second one, should we conclude that ∈ is not a relation?

Comment: '∈' is a fundamental *predicate*, it isn't a relation as in a set of ordered pairs. The closest you can get to defining such a set is to use the [axiom of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification), but it only works if you restrict to a pre-existing set that x and y involved belong to.

Comment: You are confusing relation symbols of the language (in set theory there is only one: **∈**) with relations as mathematical objects, i.e. sets, because in set theory everything is a set. It mat help to read the introductory chapters of some set theory book, like e.g. [Enderton's](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Elements_of_Set_Theory/DOnkAH-I02sC) one. There you can find the explanation about the way set theory proves that specific sets exist.

Comment: @Conifold: I don't see your point. The symbol $\in$ has arity two, so in any structure interpreting the language of set theory, it's a binary relation that plays the role of $\in$. I mean, if $(U,\epsilon)$ is a structure interpreting the language of set theory, then $\{(x,y) \ \vert \ x\epsilon y\}$ is indeed a set, it's just that this set is not represented as an element of $U$, if $(U,\epsilon)$ is a model of set theory. That is, there is no $u \in U$ whose $\epsilon$-elements are exactly the $\epsilon$-couples $(x,y)$ where $x \epsilon y$.

Comment: @Plop  {<x,y>| x ∈ y} is not a set in ZF because ZF does not allow unrestricted comprehension, it is not even a class because there are no classes in ZF. Specification only allows forming a set of ordered pairs with their elements from a fixed set. Comprehension was restricted by Zermelo to block Russell's paradox.

Comment: Yes. I said something else.